# Vue: how to merge two reactive objects without loosing reactivity

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Consider this illustrative example:

```js
const useFeatureX = () => {
  return Vue.reactive({
    x1: 2,
    x2: 3
  });
};

const useFeatureY = () => {
  return Vue.reactive({
    y1: 1,
    y2: 2
  });
};

const App = {
  setup() {
    return { ...useFeatureX(), ...useFeatureY() };
  }
};

Vue.createApp(App).mount("#root");
```

```css
input {
  max-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="root">
  x1 + x2: <input type="number" v-model="x1"/> + <input type="number" v-model="x2"/> = {{ +x1 + +x2 }} <br/>
  y1 + y2: <input type="number" v-model="y1"/> + <input type="number" v-model="y2"/> = {{ +y1 + +y2 }}
</div>
```

As you can see when you run the snippet, after merging two objects from `useFeatureX()` and `useFeatureY()` into one `{ ...useFeatureX(), ...useFeatureY() }`, the app doesn't track updates anymore.

How to merge two reactive objects without loosing reactivity?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Object destructuring breaks reactivity](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-fundamentals.html#destructuring-reactive-state).

> When we want to use a few properties of the large reactive object, it could be tempting to use ES6 destructuring
> to get properties we want:
>
> [...]
>
> Unfortunately, with such a destructuring the reactivity for both
> properties would be lost. For such a case, we need to convert our
> reactive object to a set of refs. These refs will retain the reactive
> connection to the source object:

Instead, you can use
[`toRefs`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#torefs) to
"[convert] a reactive object to a plain object where each property of
the resulting object is a ref pointing to the corresponding property
of the original object".

```js
const useFeatureX = () => {
  return Vue.reactive({
    x1: 2,
    x2: 3
  });
};

const useFeatureY = () => {
  return Vue.reactive({
    y1: 1,
    y2: 2
  });
};

const App = {
  setup() {
    return { ...Vue.toRefs(useFeatureX()), ...Vue.toRefs(useFeatureY()) };
  }
};

Vue.createApp(App).mount("#root");
```

```css
input {
  max-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="root">
  x1 + x2: <input type="number" v-model="x1"/> + <input type="number" v-model="x2"/> = {{ +x1 + +x2 }} <br/>
  y1 + y2: <input type="number" v-model="y1"/> + <input type="number" v-model="y2"/> = {{ +y1 + +y2 }}
</div>
```

Comment: What about vue2 solution? 

Comment: With vue 2.7, this is now possible with the same API.